# Method to verify a array string values?

Tags: c#, validation

I have a method, I want to be able to verify a string array inside the method. But how would I do it if the string array increase and decrease by the amount of values for example one string might have 2 items, and the next might have 3 items in the string array??

If I have a string that is more than what i have inside the method, i get error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. 
Here's my method so far:

```
string1 = "item1, item2";
string2 = "item01, item02, item03";

private void VerifyArrayString(string theString)
{
    var elements = theString.Splitnew[] { ',' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for(int i=0; i<elements.Length; i +=1)
    {
       if(elements[0] != null)
       {
           //do something
       }
           if(elements[1] != null)
           {
               //do something
           }
               // and so and so with the next items....
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing by 3 instead of 1?  And why aren't you using `i` for the index?

Comment: why r you increasing `i` thrice? `array`s can be handled more easily.

Comment: typo. recheck the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to make sure you have enough elements for what you're trying to do, you would have to do something like this:

```
string string1 = "item1, item2";
string string2 = "item01, item02, item03";

private void VerifyArrayString(string theString)
{
    var elements = theString.Split(new[] { ',' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (elements.Length >= (minimumNumber))
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i += 3)
        {
            if (elements[0] != null)
            {
                //do something
            }
            if (elements[1] != null)
            {
                //do something
            }
            // and so and so with the next items....
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want to be able to change some numbers and not all, you'd have to go through each one you're changing and make sure you have the right length, such as:

```
if(elements.Length > 0 && elements[0] != null)
{
    //do something
}
//etc etc etc
```

Revised for clarity:

Based on your comment, you'll want to check your array length each time you're trying to manipulate one of the values of the array.  Here is the example code:

```
string string1 = "item1, item2";
string string2 = "item01, item02, item03";

private void VerifyArrayString(string theString)
{
    var elements = theString.Split(new[] { ',' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for(int i=0; i<elements.Length; i++)
    {
       if(elements[i] != null)
       {
           //do something
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the same method on any string array whether the string has two items or three items or four item or what without the method failing when excessing the items in the string.

Comment: it errors out as soon as i get to If(elements[4] !-null) ..... since there's not element to read for that index.

Comment: Then you will want to use that second code snippet, check if elements.length > # && elements[#] != null

Comment: but then, if i was to console log the element, it will output three time base on the amount of element i have?

Comment: I dont understand what you're asking. What would you be trying to do?

Comment: if i put "console.log(elements[0].ToString()); inside one of the if statements, it will output it three times.

Comment: It will output it only as many times as that if statement is being evaluated true.

It sounds like you don't really need a for loop for what you're doing.

Comment: What is the "do something" going to be? Is it going to be different for each element or the same?

Comment: I just want to excess each item in a string array and output them and verify if it matches what I'm looking for.

Comment: See the code change above.  If you want to do the same thing to each element you don't need to reference the index specifically (as in elements[0]).  You use the counter in the for loop to access the index and do what you need to do.

Comment: in the "do something" if the elements is not null, how do you excess each element to a string variable??

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to filter with [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
private void VerifyArrayString(string theString)
{
    var elements = theString.Split(new[] { ',' }, 
                                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (var element in elements.Where(el => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(el))
    {
        if (element == "SomeString")
        {
           // Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

This will only yield elements which are not `null` or an empty string.

Comment: would this go through the string array whether it has 2, 3 or 4 items in the string?

Comment: @TheNewGuyOnTheRock Yes.

Comment: I want to be able to excess each of those items individually though.

Comment: @TheNewGuyOnTheRock That's exactly what a [foreach loop does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx). Each iteration, the `element` variable will be the next item in the array.

Comment: using the same method in my post and updating it with your foreach.... loop, it fails when i have a string array with three items in there. same error as what was on my post.

Comment: @TheNewGuyOnTheRock Are you still accessing elements via an indexer? It isn't possible that you get the same exception if you're doing it with a foreach loop.

Comment: what do you purpose on how to excess each items in the array?

Comment: With the `element` field declared inside the `foreach (var element in..)`

Comment: yes, but how would i use it inside the foreach loop to get each elements? elements[0] ?